# c++ multiple condition to match exact string

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I wish to look for exact match of the variable "check". If the user types "type o" or "type b", the loop will end. I tried `while (check != "type o"){...}` and it works, but not with a second condition. I am confused. Below is my code.

```
void sunTypeCheck(string sunCheck){
    string check = sunCheck;

    transform(check.begin(), check.end(), check.begin(), ::tolower);

    while (check != "type o" || check != "type b"){ //This is the problem.
        cout << "Please enter a valid type of Sun. Try again: ";
        getline(cin, check);
        transform(check.begin(), check.end(), check.begin(), ::tolower);
    }
}
```

Here is my main method.

```
int main(){
cout << "Please enter sun type: ";
         getline(cin, typeOfSun);
         sunTypeCheck(typeOfSun);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I look online and tried using "compare" but as long as I included a second condition, it will not work, and program will always return `Please enter a valid type of Sun. Try again:`

Comment: Think about what `||`(or) does.  If one side is `true` what does the expression evaluate to?

Comment: You want the condition to be true if `check` is not `"type o"` ***and*** not `"type b"`? And please learn basic [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while loop breaks when the condition become false.

```
check != "type o" || check != "type b"
```

**note: 

|| operator returns true when one of the conditions returns true
and false if its both false.**

so lets say you entered "type o"
it will be like this:

```
"type o" != "type o" || "type o" != "type b"
```

the first condition returns false and the second will return true.

```
false || true
```

so what did i say when one of the condition of || operator returns true? yes, it will be true.

so to fix this you must use && operator

```
while(check != "type o" && check != "type b")
```

**Edit:**
for && operator, it returns false when one of the condition is false and returns true if and only if both condition is true.

Comment: OH I understand now! Thank you guys!! Your explanation was the easiest to read!

Answer (score 2):

Let's apply de Morgans laws to see what we have:

```
check != "type o" || check != "type b"
```

is equivalnet to:

```
!(check == "type o" && check == "type b")
```

So the loop will continue as long as `check` is not equal to **both** strings at the **same time**. That is always true of course, since the strings are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (check != "type o" && check != "type b")
```

Comment: This solves the problem but adding some explanations never hurts anyone ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it is difficult for you to understand negative logic in condition, replace it with positive:

```
while ( true ) {
   if( check == "type o"  || check == "type b") break;
   ...
}
```

same pattern will be useful in your case to fix your program logic - you should not have code, that is doing the same multiple times ( `getline` and `transform` in your case is duplicated). Also when you try to fix value in your function you modify local copy. So better implementation would be:

```
std::string getTypeOfSun()
{
    string sun;
    while( true ) {
        cout << "Please enter a type of Sun: ";
        getline( cin, sun );
        transform(sun.begin(), sun.end(), sun.begin(), ::tolower);
        if( sun == "type o"  || sun == "type b") 
            break;
        cout << "Invalid type of Sun, try again..." << endl;
    }
    return sun;
}


int main(){
    string typeOfSun = getTypeOfSun();
    ...
}
```